# Minify output from rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, c++11, rapidjson

I am using [rapidjson](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson) to output some data for doing some statistic and plotting of a c++ programms algorithm like an internal runtime snapshots of the algorithm.

I output json like this:

```
string filename="output.json";
StringBuffer sb;
PrettyWriter<StringBuffer> writer(sb);
writer.StartArray();
for (std::vector<O_Class>::const_iterator netItr = O_Class_Array.begin();   netItr != O_Class_Array.end(); ++netItr)
    netItr->Serialize(writer);
writer.EndArray();

ofstream out;
out.open(filename);
out << sb.GetString() ;
```

As files become quite big (~100MiB) i'd like to output minified json, but I didn't find a documented way of doing so.
With an external minifier I shrunk filesize from 100 to 18MB and like to have the same result as native in my application.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `PrettyWriter` for `Writer`.

And you could ZIP the content too. This will significantly reduce the size.

Comment: Quite obvious, but totally didn't recognized these two different Writers :) Thank you very much!